# Segmentation fault with pthread_join

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

Here is the function which is giving segfault in pthread_join:

---

```
void call_merge()    
{    
    int no_runs = No_sub_seq;    
        int no_joins=no_runs-1;
    int magic1=0,j=0,inc = 1;
    int temp_runs = no_runs/2;        
    int i,k;
    while(temp_runs!=0)    
    {
        magic1=0;
        std::list<pthread_t> threadList;
        pthread_t thread;
        for(i=0;i<=temp_runs-1;i++)
        {
                    if((magic1 + inc) <= no_joins)    
                    {
                        data *d=(data *)malloc(sizeof(data));

                        d->a=magic1;
                        d->b=magic1+inc;
                        d->c=inc;
                         pthread_create(&thread,NULL,(void* (*)(void*))merge, (void*)d);  
                         threadList.push_front(thread);

                    }
                    magic1 = magic1 + (inc * 2); 
        }
        std::list<pthread_t>::iterator m;
        for(m=threadList.begin();m!=threadList.end();m++)
                pthread_join(*m,NULL);
        if((no_runs % 2) != 0)
            temp_runs++;    
        no_runs = temp_runs;
        temp_runs = no_runs/2;     
        inc = inc * 2;
        }
}
```

---

here is the merge function

---

```
void merge(void *param)
{
    data *d=(data *)param;

    int low=Sq[d->a],high;

    int mid=Sq[d->b]-1;

    if(Sq[d->b + d->c]==0)
        high=size-1;
    else
        high=Sq[d->b + d->c]-1;

    int k;

    int i=0;
    int j=low;

    while(j<=mid)
        b[i++]=a[j++];

    i=0; k=low;
    while (k<j && j<=high)
        if (b[i]<=a[j])
            a[k++]=b[i++];
        else
            a[k++]=a[j++];

    while (k<j)
        a[k++]=b[i++];

}
```

the merge function called in the above code simply merges the subarrays passed using the parameters d->a,d->b,d->c. and there is no thread code written in the merge function. The above program works fine when there are no threads and gives sorted sequence of the input array.When i tried to debug this using gdb, it shows a segault in pthread_join(). I am unable to figure out why is it happening so??? thanks in advance

Comment: doesn't answer your question, but since you are using c++, you should allocate your `d` variable with: `data *d = new data;` it is simpler. Just remember to release it with `delete` and not `free`.

Answer (score 2):

One of your calls to [pthread_create()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_create/) is probably failing, e.g. because you're exceeding the limit on the total number of threads per process.

In that case `thread` contains an undefined value. Since you ignore the error, you go ahead and store that undefined value in your list, then call [pthread_join()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_join/) on it later, which results in a segfault.

**EDIT:** Now that you handle errors from `pthread_create()`, the segfault is gone but some of your threads still don't get created, so they can't perform their work. That's why your code works with a range of `1000` but doesn't with range of `10000`.

Your design seems well-suited for [thread pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern), i.e. spawning a fixed number of threads and give them more work as soon as they finish their current tasks. See [here](http://www.hlnum.org/english/projects/tools/threadpool/doc.html) or [there](http://fixunix.com/linux/6458-pthread-threadpool.html) for pool implementations using POSIX threads.

Comment: if(pthread_create(&thread,NULL,(void* (*)(void*))merge, (void*)d)==0)     
threadList.push_front(thread);

Comment: i have added the above line,but even then it gives segfault

Comment: @nikhil, `threadList` seems to be global. Maybe it's corrupted (or its iterators are invalidated) by one of the threads?

Comment: @nikhil, well, for instance, if you modify `threadList` from one of your worker threads while the main thread iterates over it, [mayhem will ensue](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IteratorInvalidationProblem).

Comment: @frederic: Now its not throwing segfault. But now elements are not getting sorted...what might be the reason..And if i give the range as 1000 its sorting...but if i increase the range to 10000 its not getting sorted.? why could that be?

Comment: @nikhil, you might want to spend some time debugging that code first :) If you get stuck, please post the code of your `merge()` function, possibly in another question.

Comment: @frederic: sorry to trouble you but i debugged it using gdb many times and it seems the code to be correct..and i can mail u the entire program if u want to check it out.please help me out

Comment: @nikhil, no need to email anything, just edit this question and add the code of your `merge()` function, so everyone can see it. That way, if I don't find out what's going on, someone else probably will :)

Comment: @frederic: Take a look at the merge function that i added

Answer (score 0):

At what scope do you define the `threadList` object? You `push_front` the newly created threads into the list but in your code I neither see a explicit `erase` of the joined threads, nor a RAII deleting of the entire thread list. Since you iterate over the entire list of threads you're probably calling `pthread_join` multiple times for already canceled threads...